# OPC Client throw InvalidCastException through Interop COM server

Tags: vb.net, vb6, interop, opc

Our control system provide a very old OPC server (OPCAutomation). It is a COM server. I have ever written a VB6 OPC cilent ActiveX operate very good in the past when the client console OS is Windows XP Pro. Recently the operating system of the client console changes to Windows 7 Pro (and newer control system software). But the OPC server is the same old one (COM server DLL). The control system programming enviroment ask to change to VS 2013 if the user control will embeded to control system graphic. I have to re-write the program using .NET to interop DLL. The program logic is the same. But the line  *Group.OPCItems.Add(...)*  throw a InvalidCastException "Cannot cast from OPCAutomation.OPCGroupClass to OPCAutomation.OPCItems.". (Where Group have been add to OPCserver successfully)

The OPCAutomation in VB6 object browser is as follow:

[OPCGroup in OPCAutomation.dll shows the default member is OPCItems)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xpTEA.png)

[OPCItems has a "add" method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2bJKq.png)

And the VB.Net program lines are as follow (almost the same as old VB6 program. Remove try block and other non-OPC client statements)

```
Dim svr as OPCServer
Dim Group as OPCGroup
....... (and other declaration)

svr = new OPCServer
svr.Connect(strOPCServer)   ' strOPCServer is the server name
Group = svr.OPCGroup.Add(strGroupName)
Group.IsActive = False
Group.OPCItems.Add(TagNo, strTag, ClientHandles, ServerHandles, Errors1)    ' this line throw InvalidCastException
Group.SyncRead(OPCDataSource.OPCDevice, TagNo, ServerHandles, Values, Errors2)
svr.OPCGroups.RemoveAll()
svr.Disconnect()

........ (other post treatments)
```

In the Interop.OPCAutomation.dll, it shows the OPCItems is the default property of IOPCGroup interface. And the OPCItems should return a OPCItems pointer. But it seems return the wrong interface.

How should I modify the program to let Group.OPCItems.Add won't throw InvalidCastException?

A very interesting thing is if I write a .EXE client in VB6, it works. But VB.Net or c# fail. It means something wrong in type library?

(I have no .NET programming experience, very little VB6 experience. And sorry for my bad English.)

Comment: The exception says that you are trying to add a group to a group.  That doesn't make much sense.  That this is possible at all looks like a quirk in the wrapper, surely you should be using the AddItems() method?

Comment: Almost all OPC server provide AddItem() method. But the OPC server I use provide add() method. And as I have said the old VB6 client runs without any problem. But the VB.Net or c# (2013) throw such exception. It seems the problem comes from Inerop.OPCAutomation.dll. I don't know how to modify the Interop.OPCAutomation.il or use other function call to let OPCGroup.OPCItems return pointer of OPCItems instead of OPCGroup class. Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: Make sure you are explicitly building the .NET EXE for 32-bit x86.  Also, can you post the whole stack trace of the exception?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Finally the vendor's new wrapper solves the problem. The original VB6 program runs smoothly.